# Google Area Chart data mounted

Tags: gchart

I need seperate labels mounted for example:
[image]

this is an Area Chart from Google Chart. is posible change distance of label to points?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved it, only need add atribute "stem" to an annotations, i share the solution:

series: {
            0: {
                pointSize: 5,
                annotations: {
                    textStyle: {
                        auraColor: 'none',
                        bold: true,
                        fontSize: 11
                    }
                }
            },
            1: {pointSize: 5,
                annotations: {
                    **stem: { length: 20 },**
                    textStyle: {
                        auraColor: 'none',
                        bold: true,
                        fontSize: 11,
                    }
                }
            },
}

The result:
[image]

I hope it help anyone,

Regards